# How to redirect to previous page from multiple places?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm likely missing something really simple here...

Say I have model called `Option`. I then list these options in the view, with Enable / Disable buttons that lead to a controller action which then enables or disables that particular `Option`.

If the list is only in one place, I know just to call `redirect_to` or `render` to have the user go back to correct page, since there's only one.

What if the same list is in multiple places?

Meaning, if there's only one controller with enable / disable actions, how do I make that controller "return" the user to the page where they clicked the button?

I thought about keeping the previous page in a session variable or something but that seems wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `redirect_to :back` or `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: can't believe I didn't know that

Comment: @jvnill You are getting so much reputation in the past days! Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/topusers Congrat's ;)